# how to create symbols in macro from passed args

Tags: clojure

Just experimenting macros limitations or unknowns, I am not able make fixed len arity to symbol map with changed keys in run time.
So when k1 k2 are passed as args to process-arity, it should create j1 j2 symbols for accessing k1 and k2 values in syms-from-map macro.
Giving compile error:
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.core$map
quoting unquoting makes difficult to write macros :-(

```
(defmacro syms-from-map[m]
  `(let [~@(mapcat (fn[[k v]] [k v]) (var-get (resolve m)))] 
     (prn "got" ~'j1 ~'j2))
  )

(defmacro process-arity[args]
  `(let [] (fn ~args 
     (let [~'map1 (zipmap '[j1 j2] ~args)] 
       (syms-from-map ~'map1)
       ))))
(def test-m1 (process-arity [k1 k2]))
(apply test-m1 [1 2])
```

Comment: Where are all these obscure macro issues coming from? Is it chance, or is there a course or something thaybis suggesting everyone go macro-wild?

Answer (score 0):

`macroexpand-1` is a valuable tool. Use it.

```
(defmacro process-arity[args]
    `(let [] (fn ~args
                 (let [~'map1 (zipmap [~'j1 ~'j2] ~args)]
                     (syms-from-map ~'map1)))))
```

`(syms-from-map ~'map1)` won't work the way you expect. I suggest you convert it to a function.

Comment: By converting it to function if I generate j1, j2 symbols, how can those symbols be passed to other macro from syms-from-map fn ?